# Can you guys help me diagnose these pepper leaves? Crinkly?

Tags: peppers, nutrients

Here is an image.

[image: crinkled pepper leaves]

Is it cal/mag issue maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be Calcium deficiency in the soil, but if you use a standard fertilizer it is not quite likely.

Look carefully after any signs of diseases like mosaic pattern (virus), dark spots (fungus), or mites and aphids on the underside of the leaves.
If no signs found, [then it is probably](https://peppergeek.com/pepper-plant-diseases-problems/#curling-leaves-pepper-plants)

> a sign of either too much light, too much water, or plant edema

Answer (score 1):

The way the leaves are curling up all around looks a lot like boron deficiency. That might just mean that the soil pH is too high, but it might mean your soil is low on boron.

If you add boron, you should know it's a dangerous activity if you're not both educated about boron-supplementation and careful, and it's easy to add too much (which could have long-term consequences to your soil). A foliar spray would probably be safer. I'm not sure how much to use for a foliar spray, however (but too much could easily kill your plant).

Tomato Yellow Leaf Curl virus causes similar symptoms, along with chlorosis and undersized leaves in tomatoes. It does infect peppers, but I'm not sure what symptoms it causes in them.

The crinkly factor might seem to indicate calcium-deficiency, but if your pH is high, I would doubt that (since calcium is often what causes a high pH). Calcium-deficiency tends to cause some deformations along with crinkliness, and I don't see any deformations.